# WordPress Export/Import for custom options.php values?

Tags: import, export

I've just discovered the WordPress export/import routine under the tools menu. However, upon testing it for the first time, several values stored in my wp_options table did not transfer over.

Is there a way to include those values when exporting/importing a site?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I've caught up on my answer checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply read the text, the import/export plugins offer:

> Upload your WordPress eXtended RSS (WXR) file and we’ll import the posts, pages, comments, custom fields, categories, and tags into this site.

Comment: You don't have to be a smart@ss about it. Thanks for pointing it out none the less. A little civility goes a long way ;-)

Comment: @N2Mystic "Civility": Yes, but I hope "simply read the text" isn't harsh (only brief/short). Aynway, there're lots of people asking Qs that a) don't add value to WPSE Q/A as reference for later readers and b) don't have the "civility" to mark the As as solved, so later readers can see if the Q is solved in the overview and b) help moderators & answerers to make the "unanswered" list smaller.